# Performance advantage or just for convenience?

Tags: mysql, architecture, sequelize.js

Is there a performance advantage to using Sequelize or is it simply for convenience? If just for convenience I don't get it. If you want it to be convenient why not just use a document based database like Mongo? If you want to use SQL, how about we just actually use SQL? It seems a hassle for not much "convenience" advantage, and wondering what all the fuss is about? Is it intended for people stuck on SQL, but don't want to write joins?

Comment: It certainly will never be for sql performance. But like for many ORMs I would recommend my grandma start there because most of her queries would be simple. March that down a few weeks and then devs get frustrated in how to do medium difficult queries. And you see that in the questions under any ORM. But, tie ORMS into models and attempt to take care of most things, offer RAW as an escape route, that is pretty good (if that is what you wanna do). Some of us would never imagine using an ORM. Hopefully we can respect those that do. Don't forget, performance also includes get simple things done

Answer (score 0):

According to the `sequelize` documentation

> It features solid transaction support, relations, eager and lazy loading, read replication and more.

When it comes to performance, using an ORM such as `Sequelize` can offer certain benefits over using raw SQL queries. For instance, `Sequelize` can assist you in creating more scalable and maintainable code by offering high-level abstractions for interacting with databases. Nonetheless, the performance of `Sequelize` (or any other ORM) in comparison to raw SQL queries may differ based on the specific situation.